# Remove Dictionary Key, if Value is empty

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

Goal: Have a **dictionary-comprehension** that removes a given key, if its respective value is *"empty"*.

**Empty** means anything such as: `[], 0, None, 0.0, ""` etc.

Code:

```
thisdict =  {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": ''  # [], 0, None, 0.0, "" etc.
}
print(thisdict)

thisdict = {val for key, val in thisdict.items() if val}  # Attempt
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post to help further clarify.

Comment: Will not do again in future, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
thisdict = {val for key, val in thisdict.items() if val}
```

is set-comprehension, if you need dict-comprehension do

```
thisdict = {key:val for key, val in thisdict.items() if val}
```

See [PEP 274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) for further discussion of *Dict Comprehensions*

Comment: Ahh thank you! Just as @Sayse pointed out

Answer (score 2):

You can use built in method of python [Dictionary(get)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp)

```
{key:value for key,value in thisdict.items() if thisdict.get(key)}
```

Comment: How might I tell which out of yours and @Daweo 's would run quicker? I do have a fairly large dictionary. More out of curiosity

Comment: i think the @@Daweo 's code would run quicker but am not sure.